# How to create a data frame in R (without using nested for loops), which records estimations from other vectors?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, nested-for-loop

I want to store the distances between each point (x,y) of two 2D trajectories. So I have 4 vectors: `ax`, `ay` that has time dependent coordinates of particle a and `bx`, `by` for particle b. I want to create a data frame `dist` that will basically be:

```
dist[t1,t2] = sqrt((ax[t1]-bx[t2])**2+(ay[t1]-by[t2])**2)
```

Now I want to do this without using nested for loops with `t1` and `t2`, as it will take a lot of time for `tmax~1000`. Is there any cool dataframe trick or any of the `apply` methods to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `outer` function is useful for this, you could do:

```
outer(seq_along(ax), seq_along(bx), 
function(t1,t2){sqrt((ax[t1]-bx[t2])**2+(ay[t1]-by[t2])**2)})
```

I've made a slight change to your calculation: `bx[t1]` became `bx[t2]`, which I think is correct

Answer (score 1):

First, let's make the data reproducible. You should do that yourself in your next questions.

```
ax <- 1:3
ay <- 4:6
bx <- 3:1
by <- 6:4
```

R being vectorized, you don't need to include indexes in your statement.

```
dist <- sqrt((ax-bx)^2+(ay-by)^2)
result <- data.frame(ax, ay, bx, by, dist)
> result
  ax ay bx by     dist
1  1  4  3  6 2.828427
2  2  5  2  5 0.000000
3  3  6  1  4 2.828427
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted. What you did is basically the distance between two particles at each instant of time. I need the distance between each point of trajectory and each point of trajectory b. So it will be a matrix (dataframe) of dimension tmax X tmax.